# Cloud functions - event.data.val() returns previous value for its map child

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

[image: Firebase Database]

As you can see in the screenshots I can't update /upvoters/ inside /user_events/{uid}/{eventId}. /events/{uid} is updated from client and it works. when I tried console.log to debug my cloud function code i realized events.data.val() returns not the updated but previous value for /upvoters/ , but it receives the current value for "rating". Below are both my client and cloud codes.

EDIT: vote() updates `events/{eventId}` and cloud functions copies the same value to `/user_events/{uid}/{eventId}`. i don't see how vote() is useless. what am i trying to do is update the `user_events` when I update the `events{eventId}` with vote() and it does update except for `/upvoters/`. so basically what happens is; when the vote() first executes `/events/upvoters/` is created with vote(), `exports.set_user_events` sets whole event to `/user_events/{eventId}/upvoters/` which works well. when vote() runs a second time, i remove the upvoter inside upvoters map, `events/{eventId}/` is updated then my cloud functions works, i have debugged it with console.log commands and have seen right at this point `event.data.val()` returns as if the upvoters wasn't removed but other values such as rating is updated values.
 so `user_events/{uid}/{eventId}/` is updated except for its upvoters child.

Cloud code :

```
// Add an event to user_events
exports.set_user_events = functions.database.ref('social/events/{pushId}')
    .onWrite((event) => {
        const original = event.data.val();
        console.log('testValue',original);
        return admin.database().ref('social/user_events/' + original.owner.uid + "/" + event.params.pushId).set(original);
    });
```

Android code:

```
  void vote(String eventId) {
        final DatabaseReference eventRef = rootRef.child("events").child(eventId);
        eventRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                Event e = mutableData.getValue(Event.class);

                if (e == null) {
                    return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                }

                if(e.upvoters!=null) {
                    if(!e.upvoters.containsKey(currentUser.getUid())) {
                        e.upvoters.put(currentUser.getUid(),true);
                        e. rating = e.rating + 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        e.upvoters.remove(currentUser.getUid());
                        e.rating = e.rating - 1;

                    }
                }
                else {
                    Map<String,Boolean> upvoters = new HashMap<>();
                    upvoters.put(currentUser.getUid(),true);
                    e.rating = e.rating + 1;
                    e.upvoters = upvoters;
                }

                mutableData.setValue(e);
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                                   DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking for here or what's wrong. The Android vote() code is completely useless since you call `admin.database().ref('social/user_events/' + original.owner.uid + "/" + event.params.pushId).set(original);`, which replaces `social/user_events/userid/pushid` with whatever is at `social/events/pushid`.

Comment: @Kato updated the question. i tried to explain it with more details.